# ¿Por qué me aparece este error TypeError: Person() takes no arguments al compilar esto?

Tags: python-3.7

```
class Person:
    def __int__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("talk")
            
john = Person("John Wick")
print(john.name)
john.talk()`
```

Comment: Es un error tipografico. Deberia ser `__init__` (abreviatura de *initialize*) en vez de `__int__` (parecido a *integer*).

Answer (score 1):

Se escribe `__init__`

Te falto la "i".

La versión correcta:

```
class Person:
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("talk")
            
john = Person("John Wick")
print(john.name)
john.talk()
```

Le pasa a todo el mundo ...

Comment: Muchas gracias!